# Get ImageView JAVA ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Need to know which type i need to call to store my image in my Database.

Here is my code :

DBHelper.java

```
            public boolean insertDataGame(String name, String price, String description, String typeConsole, byte[] image) {
    SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_NAME, name);
    cv.put(COL_PRICE, price);
    cv.put(COL_DESC, description);
    cv.put(COL_TYPE, typeConsole);
    cv.put(COL_IMAGE, image);
    long res = MyDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    if (res == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

add.java

```
           // class add.java 
       add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                 // function insertDataGame
                MyDB.insertDataGame(name.getText().toString(),desc.getText().toString(), price.getText().toString(),
                        type.getText().toString(), image. " i don't know");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You generally shouldn't be putting an image in the database.  You save it to the filesystem, and save the name of the file in the database.

Comment: And after how do i retrieve my photo to display it ?

Comment: By opening the file that you saved it to, using BitmapFactory.decodeFile()

Comment: Okay great thank you ! I’m going to try this